# What does a gold rank emblem indicate in Spies vs. Mercs in Splinter Cell: Black List?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

In the player listing, while playing Spies vs. Mercs, I've noticed that sometimes the rank emblem is gold (or yellow). I can't find a pattern; usually it's white, but sometimes it's gold, and it changes sometimes, even for the same player. (For example, mine is usually white, but sometimes it's colored gold instead.) What does the color indicate?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really. It's like every ten levels it's a gold emblem until you get to the 50's where you're nearing the highest rank of 56 where it's always gold.